# Ignoring case sensitive in c#

Tags: c#, comparison, case-sensitive

I have 2 string that I am comparing but I need to avoid problem if I use upper case or lower case.

There's any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
if (userID >= 0 && fnIndex >= 0 && lnIndex >= 0)
{
for (int i = 1; i < userDataId.Length; i++)
    {
     var userData = userDataId[i].List;
         if (userData[fnIndex].ToString() == "FIRSTNAME1" &&
         userData[lnIndex].ToString() == "LASTNAME1")
         {
            userId = userData[userID].ToString();
            break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please always *first* google your question title before you ask for help.

Comment: look answer below or use the `.ToLower()` Method of the string class. but in this case the answer below should be better

Comment: @JensHorstmann -- Your comment is wrong considering the strings being compared against are in uppercase.

Comment: @roryap then he should use `.ToUpper()`

Comment: I did google it and I was not find it anything concrete. @roryap, thanks for the reply, your solution worked!

Comment: @Aarancibia -- It's always better to demonstrate that you researched even if you couldn't come up with anything.  Provide an indication that you searched for something, what you *did* find that didn't match your question, or what it was you were hoping to find.  Thus, you'll avoid down votes.

Comment: @roryap you're right I should include more comments about my researches. I will do it next time. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (and should always) do this to compare strings instead of using `==`:

```
if (userData[fnIndex].ToString().Equals(
    "FIRSTNAME1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Also, `"FIRSTNAME1"` and `"LASTNAME1"` should be made into constants.

Comment: Thank you!, It worked. I have changed it for first name and last name and both works. Thanks for the help